# Converting a block of code into a function results in error

Tags: python, pandas

i was trying to clean up a snippet of code but when migrate a part of code into a function it started pushing me an exception, see as below:

Here is the snippet which I want to clean up:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

df = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv', sep=';')

labels = list(df.columns)
for index, label in enumerate(labels):
    labels[index] = labels[index].replace(' ', '_')


substance = 'pH'
median = df[substance].mean()
for index, substance in enumerate(df[substance]):
    if substance >= median:
        df.loc[index, substance] = 'high'
    else:
        df.loc[index, substance] = 'low'
print(df.groupby(substance).quality.mean())
```

The idea is to create two functions instead and call them anytime i need to evaluate a substance, with that in mind i did:

```
def substance_mean(substance):
    return df[substance].mean()

def substance_evaluation(substance):
    for index, substance in enumerate(df[substance]):
        if substance >= substance_mean(substance):
            df.loc[index, substance] = 'high'
        else:
            df.loc[index, substance] = 'low'
    print(df.groupby(substance).quality.mean())

substance_evaluation('pH')
```

When i ran the code the following exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atila/Desktop/estudos/udacity/aws_ML/venv-ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 3.51

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/atila/Desktop/estudos/udacity/aws_ML/app.py", line 34, in <module>
    substance_evaluation('pH')
  File "/home/atila/Desktop/estudos/udacity/aws_ML/app.py", line 28, in substance_evaluation
    if substance >= substance_mean(substance):
  File "/home/atila/Desktop/estudos/udacity/aws_ML/app.py", line 24, in substance_mean
    return df[substance].mean()
  File "/home/atila/Desktop/estudos/udacity/aws_ML/venv-ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2800, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/home/atila/Desktop/estudos/udacity/aws_ML/venv-ml/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2648, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 3.51
```

Comment: BTW: function `substance_mean()` is not good idea - you run it many times in loop to get always the same value.  Better use `median = df[substance].mean()`. Besides creating function to run only one line of code seems waste of time.

Comment: I think you could write it all without `for`-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run it but all your problem is that inside `substance_evaluation()` you use the same name `substance` for two variables which should keep different values.

First you have `substance` in

```
 def substance_evaluation(substance)
```

and this variable should keep `"ph"` but later you use

```
 for ..., substance in ...:
```

which assign different value to this variable (in place of `"ph"`) and later you use

```
 ... >= substance_mean(substance)
```

to calculate `mean` for `"ph"` but in this moment `substance` doesn't have value `"ph"` but `3.51` (as show error `KeyError: 3.51`)

You wouldn't have this problem if in function you would keep

```
 median = df[substance].mean()
```

and

```
 if substance >= median:
```

Besides using function to run single line of code is waste of time.

And keeping this line you calculate median only once - before loop. Using function inside loop you calculate the same value many times - and it is also waste of time.

---

I think in both version (with and without function) you can still have problem with `substance` because you use it also in `df.loc[index, substance]` so it may try to do `df.loc[index, 3.51]` instead of `df.loc[index, "ph"]`. You should use different name ie. `value`

```
for ..., value in ...:
    if value >= median:
```

---

You should have one function like this:

```
def substance_evaluation(substance):

    median = df[substance].mean()

    for index, value in enumerate(df[substance]):
        if value >= median:
            df.loc[index, substance] = 'high'
        else:
            df.loc[index, substance] = 'low'

    print(df.groupby(substance).quality.mean())
```

---

But I think you could write it simple.

```
def substance_evaluation(substance):

    median = df[substance].mean()

    mask = (df[substance] >= mediam)

    df[substance][  mask ] = 'high'
    df[substance][ ~mask ] = 'low'

    print(df.groupby(substance).quality.mean())
```

---

Eventually with `np.where()`

```
def substance_evaluation(substance):

    median = df[substance].mean()

    mask = (df[substance] >= mediam)

    df[substance] = np.where(mask, 'high', 'low')

    print(df.groupby(substance).quality.mean())
```

In this version you can easily create new column with values

```
    df["new column"] = np.where(mask, 'high', 'low')
```

---

**EDIT:** Minimal working code for test

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import time

def version1(df, substance):
    median = df[substance].mean()
    for index, value in enumerate(df[substance]):
        if value >= median:
            df.loc[index, substance] = 'high'
        else:
            df.loc[index, substance] = 'low'

def version2(df, substance):
    median = df[substance].mean()
    mask = (df[substance] >= median)
    df[substance][  mask ] = 'high'
    df[substance][ ~mask ] = 'low'

def version3(df, substance):
    median = df[substance].mean()
    mask = (df[substance] >= median)
    df[substance] = np.where(mask, 'high', 'low')

# ---

random.seed(0) # to generate always the same values

df = pd.DataFrame({'pH': [random.randint(0,7) for _ in range(5)]})

substance = 'pH'

print('--- before ---')
print(df)

# ---

df1 = df.copy()
start = time.time()

version1(df1, substance)

end = time.time()
print('--- after --- time:', end-start)
print(df1)

# ---

df2 = df.copy()
start = time.time()

version2(df2, substance)

end = time.time()
print('--- after --- time:', end-start)
print(df1)

# ---

df3 = df.copy()
start = time.time()

version3(df3, substance)

end = time.time()
print('--- after --- time:', end-start)
print(df1)
```